# Unity Container singleton based on parameters

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

is it possible in Microsoft Unity 2.0 container framework to create singletons based on certain parameters.

I want to pass parameters to the constructor which is possible but I want the container to give me a new instance if parameters are new or give me the same instance of parameters are same.

Comment: Have you looked into implementing your own lifetime manager?

Comment: My gut feeling is that this would be a bad practice, since it must be the container that controls the lifetime, not the application. Can you give a concrete example to shows what the problem is you are trying to solve. This allows us give feedback on the design.